# Are those languages regular or not

Tags: automata

Hi I would need help from you, I got the following languages and need to determine if are regular or not.

[image]

Now I think that Y is not regular and I applied the Pumping Lemma to determine that.
For X I am not sure if is a regular language or not, I was thinking that X is the set of strings with an odd number of a's that can be easily represented with an NFA.

Can anyone help me with that  ?

Comment: X can be rewritten as a^(2n+1); does that help?

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your reply. Mmmmmmm maybe yes I mean...in this case an automa should count the number of a ( n ) and add another a...but is that possible for an automa ? I think no...right ?

Answer (score 1):

The first one (`X`) is regular, because you can construct a finite automaton for it:

```
(start) --- a --> (final) -- a --> (state)
                     ^                |
                     \------ a -------/
```

The second one (`Y`) is not regular, because you cannot construct a finite automaton for it. It would require memory to store the number of `a` to be able to later find one more of `b`. That language is context-free, with a grammar:

```
S = T b
T = a T b
T = ε
```

Comment: I did this kind of reasoning but I was/am not sure if the language is regular or not.
For example 0^n 0^2n is regular ? This could be the language representing all the string with a number of 0's multiple of 3 that can be recognized by a DFA

Comment: A language is regular, if it has at least one regular grammar that generates all strings from the language. `X` has such a grammar: S = a T;  T = a U; T = ε; U = a T. The second language `Y` does not have a regular grammar, but only a context-free one, as I have wrote. That means that it is not a regular language. The third language `0^3n` has a regular grammar, thus it is a regular language.